# ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estou com um problema com uma Trigger (MySQL).

Tentei construí-la sozinho.

A necessidade: tenho um sistema de ocorrências onde ao passar para a etapa de encerrado (*stage* 4) ele verifique se foi digitado uma descrição no campo `descricao_encerrado`.

Antes de aplicar a *trigger* preciso verificar se a ocorrência está no *stage* 3 (nível anterior ao encerramento), vejam o que fiz até agora:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE trigger VERIFICAENCERRADA BEFORE UPDATE ON ocorrencias
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @descricao_resolvida = NEW.descricao_resolvida;
IF ((SELECT stage FROM ocorrencias WHERE OLD.stage = 3) AND  (CHAR_LENGTH(@descricao_resolvida) < 1) ) 
THEN 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Deve-se digitar uma descrição no encerramento.';
END IF;
END //
```

Porém ela está me retornando o seguinte erro ao dar o update do *stage* 3 para o 4 (encerrado):

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Não posso fazer este controle via código, é um pré requisito do professor que seja via *trigger*.

Comment: Ele esta dizendo que o SELECT stage FROM ocorrencias WHERE OLD.stage = 3 esta voltando mais de uma linha. Portanto não para comparar se é igual a 3 ou não.

Comment: Bem, o erro é exatamente isso que o @ReginaldoRigo disse. Não tem como te ajudar sem mais detalhes...

Comment: uhm, talvez passando o ID da ocorrencia também. vou testar

Comment: Como eu faria se quisesse comparar o ID da ocorrencia que estou fazendo o update com o id das ocorrencias do banco ?
não sei se me expressei direito..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu select está retornando mais de uma linha cara voce pode resolver assim

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE trigger VERIFICAENCERRADA BEFORE UPDATE ON ocorrencias
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @descricao_resolvida = NEW.descricao_resolvida;
IF ((OLD.stage = 3) AND  (CHAR_LENGTH(@descricao_resolvida) < 1) ) 
THEN 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Deve-se digitar uma descrição no encerramento.';
END IF;
END //
```

OLD  está se referindo a linha que está sendo atualizada com valores antigos, e mesmo acontecendo com o NEW, porém NEW contem os dados novos.

Comment: Caraca vocês são de mais!! obrigado galera a solução do @Wpbarcelos funcionou perfeitamente!!!